# Sketch set in the complex plane re = 0

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Problem: Describe and sketch the set $\{Z\in \mathbb C| Re(Z^3)=0\}$.

This is what I began with:

$Z^3=(x+iy)^3
    =x^3-3xy^2+(3x^2y-y^3)i$

The set seems to be completely imaginary(?) since $\ Re(Z^3)=0$

$\  Re(Z^3)= x^3-3xy^2=0$

Then I *think* this is the graph I need to sketch..

Any advice? Am I working in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest that you think *geometrically* from the start. That's a lot easier. What kind of point lands on the imaginary axis when you cube it?

But now that we're here:
$$
x^3-3xy^2=x(x-\sqrt3y)(x+\sqrt3y)
$$
is $0$ iff one (or more) of these three factors is
 zero. Each of the factors are zero along a straight line in the plane ($x=0$, for instance, is the imaginary axis itself). So your set is the union of those three lines. And yes, you *are* asked to draw it as well. Or at least sketch it.